# Asymptotic probability that chi-squared distribution exceeds its mean

Tags: asymptotics, chi-squared-distribution

Let $\chi_k$ be the chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom. $\chi_k$ has mean $k$. Is it true that
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \Pr[\chi_k \geq k] = 1/2$$
This seems pretty plausible.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on the chi-squared distribution answers this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Asymptotic_properties.

Comment: If $Q \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n),$ then $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2,$ where $Z_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ and $Z_I^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu - 1).$ Use CLT.